# How can I use multi-threading (Parallel ForEach), and batch? Or should I handle it differently?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm creating an app to send out bulk emails, but I'm lacking understanding of batch, multi-threads, or the best way to handle it.

Say I do something like this:

```
Dim options as New ParallelOptions
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 10

Parallel.ForEach(recipients.AsEnumerable(), options, _
    Function(row)
        Return SendEmail(args)
    End Function)
```

What if there are a large amount of emails? I was thinking of adding a batch option, but not sure if it's beneficial. So if I have 500,000 subscribers, could this Parallel looping become unstable? Should there be a pause or sleep at some point? When thinking of emails I think of "Batch = #" but I'm unsure of how to take this concept into multi-threading like this or if I should be doing something entirely different.

I've heard of getting blacklisted if not handled correctly

Comment: I guess it depends mainly on the email service provider you use for the outgoing mail account. If the provider disallows large quantities of outgoing mail you may get blacklisted, or locked for some time (to supress hijacked account being used for spam). It depends of course on the provider. The code itself, as long as it is thread safe, should work just fine though. It is hard to say without knowing the SendEmail method.

Comment: The SendMail() is just your typical smtp email. Similar to the function at the bottom of this site: http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-Bulk-Mass-Email-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: I guess you need to ask your email account provider then about conditions for sending large numbers of e-mails in a short amount of time on a regular basis. From a programming standpoint I don't see an immediate problem (as I said, if you made sure your code is thread safe).

Comment: Part of my reasoning for asking is this the application could be purchased, and I wanted to provide public property options for the end user based on their needs. Perhaps I need to remove the parallel and just loop through, pausing for 1 second based on batch. Still trying to figure out the best way to handle it.